# Cannot install plugin in Ionic because of cordova-common-1.1.1.tgz

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to implement tabs in my application. When I try to install the npm package:

```
npm install ionic2-super-tabs --save
```

The console prints:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HH\Documents\ionicproject\node_modules\file:cordova-common-1.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\HH\Documents\ionicproject\node_modules\file:cordova-common-1.1
.1.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where do you wnat to install? What kind of project?

Comment: I want to install the package in my Ionic project, which is an application for iOS and Android

Comment: have you installed cordova? `npm install -g ionic cordova` and then just `ionic start myproject tabs`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement tab project for ionic please use below codes in order;

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@latest

ionic start myNewProject tabs

cd myNewProject

ionic serve
```

and it will work....

Comment: I want to use it in my own project, I don't want to create a new one

Comment: Yes, but your suggestion will generate a new Ionic application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your project as a Tab. Please do below steps;

1. ionic generate tabs
2. set rootpage atrribute in app.components.ts as new Tab Page
3. then ionic serve

Comment: The problem is that I get the error regarding cordova-common-1.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! code ENOENT

Comment: Or create a simple page ionic generate page tab then modify ts file as `tab1Root = Page1;   tab2Root = Page2;...` AND add html file these codes. 
`<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>`

Comment: This `ionic2-super-tabs` library for 3rd party library for other applications not for ionic project.

Comment: I am following this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-swipeable-tabs-to-an-ionic-application/). He says that it's for Ionic 2